# How to increase computational speed of mapping function to a dataframe column in pandas

Tags: python, dataframe

I am creating a new column in a dataframe that is based on other values in the entire dataframe. I have found a couple of ways to do so (shown below), but they are very slow when working with large datasets (500k rows takes 1 hour to run). I am looking to increase the speed of this process.

I have attempt to use .apply with a lambda function. I have also used .map to obtain a list to put into the new column. Both of these methods work but are too slow.

```py
values = {'ID': ['1','2','3','4','1','2','3'],
        'MOD': ['X','Y','Z','X','X','Z','Y'],
        'Period': ['Current','Current','Current','Current','Past','Past','Past']
        }

df = DataFrame(values,columns= ['ID', 'MOD','Period'])

df['ID_MOD']=df['ID']+df['MOD']

def funct(identifier, indentifier_modification,period):
    if period=="Current":
        if (df.ID==identifier).sum()==1:
            return "New"     
        elif (df.ID_MOD==indentifier_modification).sum()==1:
            return "Unique"
        else:
            return "Repeat"
    else:
        return "n/a"
```

Initial df:

```py
  ID MOD   Period ID_MOD
0  1   X  Current     1X
1  2   Y  Current     2Y
2  3   Z  Current     3Z
3  4   X  Current     4X
4  1   X     Past     1X
5  2   Z     Past     2Z
6  3   Y     Past     3Y
```

Here are the two methods that are too slow:
1)

```py
df['new_column']=df.apply(lambda x:funct(x['ID'],x['ID_MOD'],x['Period']), axis=1)
```

2)

```py
df['new_column']=list(map(funct,df['ID'],df['ID_MOD'],df['Period']))
```

Intended final df:

```py
  ID MOD   Period ID_MOD new_column
0  1   X  Current     1X     Repeat
1  2   Y  Current     2Y     Unique
2  3   Z  Current     3Z     Unique
3  4   X  Current     4X        New
4  1   X     Past     1X        n/a
5  2   Z     Past     2Z        n/a
6  3   Y     Past     3Y        n/a
```

There are no error messages; the code just takes ~1 hour to run with a large data set.

Comment: If the computation can be parallelized perhaps you should try that?

Answer (score 0):

your current code is currently scales as O(N**2) where N is the number of rows.  if your `df` really is 500k rows this is going to take a long time!  you really want to be using code from numpy and pandas that has much lower computational complexity.

the [aggregations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) built into pandas would help a lot in place of your use of `sum`, as would learning about how pandas does indexing and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html).  in your case I can get 500k rows down to less than a second pretty easily.

start by defining a dummy data set:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 500_000

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': np.random.choice(N//2, N),
    'a': np.random.choice(list('XYZ'), N),
    'b': np.random.choice(list('CP'), N),
})
```

next we can do the aggregations to count across your various groups:

```
ids = df.groupby(['id']).size().rename('ids')
idas = df.groupby(['id','a']).size().rename('idas')
```

next we can join these aggregations back to the original data set

cutting down the data as much as possible is always a good idea and in your case `Past` values always get a value of `n/a` and as they take up half your data would seem to half the amount of work:

```
df2 = df.loc[df['b'] == 'C',]
df2 = pd.merge(df2, ids, left_on=['id'], right_index=True)
df2 = pd.merge(df2, idas, left_on=['id','a'], right_index=True)
```

finally we use `where` from numpy to vectorise all your conditions and hence work much faster, then use pandas indexing to put everything back together efficiently, patching up missing values afterwards

```
df2['out'] = np.where(
    df2['ids'] == 1, 'New',
    np.where(df2['idas'] == 1, 'Unique', 'Repeat'))

df['out'] = df2['out']
df['out'].fillna('n/a', inplace=True)
```

hope some of that helps!  for reference, the above runs in ~320ms for 500k rows on my laptop